# C# Finding how many Datagrid rows/columns are needed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell, rows

I got an assignment where I have to read text from a file and extract numbers into a `DataGrid`, so my question is how to know how many rows or/and columns I need for the `DataGrid` to look nice, and to be filled with numbers.

So if I have 9 numbers the grid should be something like 3x3 , or if I have 18 --> 6x3 etc.

The amount of numbers can be from 1 to 9999999 (a lot).

I was thinking about doing something like:

```
int x, i, j;   //x-amount of numbers,i-rows,j-columns

while (i * j < a)
{
     if (a % 2 == 0)
       {
         i++;
         j++;
       }
}
```

And so on and on and on for as many different cases as I could think of, in the end all the grids would either be half empty or completely broken and unusable like 1x17.

Comment: The `DataGrid` creates as many rows as necessary.  It has a scrollwheel if the data extends past the space available.  Also, it has an autogenerate column property to handle the columns, so really you just need to pass it a list of objects and for the most part it takes care of it.  You can fine tune it after that.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if the number is prime or not. It must not be a prime number.
2. Check if that number is divisible by any number between 2 - 20. So, lets say number is 2378, we see that 2378 = 2*1189. Generally, row count is always greater than columns. As columns represent field names. So, you have 1189 rows and 2 columns. Start from 20 backwards, as we want maximum columns in your display.

   Now, suppose you have 8645, 8645 = 455 * 19, also 8645 = 1235 * 7. So, we choose 455 * 19 => 455 rows, 19 columns.
3. Now, you have to take care of screen resolution. Thats a tricky part. But anyhow 20 columns looks reasonable in any resolution. Use `SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth` to aid you.